# To integrate swagger with karate framework

Tags: swagger, karate

I want to integrate swagger with karate framework. I searched on the internet for the resources but i could not find any resource to integrate swagger with karate. Is there any way to integrate swagger with karate?

Could anyone please provide a solution for the same

Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you expect ? karate is for testing what your server does and especially when you call multiple end-points. I personally feel that many people are confused that swagger is a "short cut" to write tests. so please explain, and we can discuss solutions.

Comment: This will be a commercial tool, work in progress and you can look at this set of demos: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-oas-demo - if interested, reach out at https://www.karatelabs.io/studio